# How do I create one common vocabulary for all Organic Groups but only allow group managers to select from and add their own terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, organic-groups

Here is the scenario. I have Organic Groups. There is only one content type that they are allowed to post in a group. This content type has a tagging widget that only allows for one tag. I need the Managers of each group to be able to only see or add tags they have created to be attached to the group post. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?